# Список в списке и сравнение Python

Tags: python, списки, сравнение

есть такая проблема на выходе функции выводит результат. Нужно как-то отфильтровать результаты, необходимо избавиться от дубликатов и комбинаций.

Например [8, 6, 4] = [4, 8, 6]

Основную функцию к сожалению модифицировать не могу, есть только результат. 
Понимаю что возможно каждый элемент проверить через циклы, но может есть более оптимизированный способ с помощью библиотек или каких-нибудь функций.

```py
result = [[1, 2], [5, 6, 3, 2], [7, 8, 6, 3], [4, 8, 6], [1, 5, 6, 3], [2, 5, 6, 3], [7, 8, 6, 3], [4, 8, 6], [2, 5, 7, 8], [1, 5, 7, 8], [6, 3, 7, 8], [4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 4], [1, 5, 6, 7, 4], [2, 8, 1, 6, 4], [8, 6, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по описанию задачи, порядок элементов во вложенных списках в результирующем списке не так важен. Поэтому можно построить множество (`set`), состоящее из отсортированных кортежей:

```
res = set(tuple(sorted(l)) for l in result)
```

результат:

```
In [26]: res
Out[26]:
{(1, 2),
 (1, 2, 4, 6, 8),
 (1, 3, 5, 6),
 (1, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 5, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 5, 6),
 (2, 5, 7, 8),
 (3, 4, 7),
 (3, 6, 7, 8),
 (4, 6, 8)}
```

PS элементами множества могут быть только хешируемые объекты. Список не является хешируемым объектом. Поэтому нам пришлось преобразовать внутренние списки в кортежи.

Если на выходе нужен список списков:

```
In [27]: [list(x) for x in res]
Out[27]:
[[1, 2],
 [1, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [3, 6, 7, 8],
 [1, 3, 5, 6],
 [1, 5, 7, 8],
 [2, 5, 7, 8],
 [3, 4, 7],
 [4, 6, 8],
 [1, 2, 4, 6, 8],
 [2, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: или так `res = set(frozenset(item) for item in result)`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, отличный вариант! Может добавите в качестве ответа?